# Pourquoi «À bout de souffle» et pas «au bout de souffle», «au bout de chemin» et pas «à bout de chemin»?

Tags: grammaire

Pourquoi dit-on «À bout de souffle» et pas «au bout de souffle», «au bout de chemin» et pas «à bout de chemin»?

Tant 'souffle' que 'chemin' sont des noms masculins, alors qu'elle est la raison de la différence de genre entre les deux expressions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Les expressions *à bout* et *au bout* ne signifient pas la même chose.

**Être *au bout*** signifie être à la fin de quelque chose, concrètement ou figurativement. Exemples :

> sa maison se trouve au bout du chemin
>
> il est arrivé au bout de sa réflexion sur son futur professionel

**Être *à bout* de quelque chose** signifie qu'on a épuisé une ressource. Exemples :

> Il est à bout de souffle (= il n'a plus de souffle)
>
> Je suis à bout d'idées (= je n'ai plus d'idées)

On peut aussi dire simplement **être *à bout*** sans complément, ce qui signifie qu'on n'a plus de patience ou de force pour accepter quelque chose. Exemples :

> Je suis à bout, je vais craquer !
>
> Il m'a poussé à bout, alors je me suis mis en colère

Comment: Merci Greg pour le renseignement. ;)

Answer (score 0):

On ne dit pas <s>au bout de chemin</s> mais « au bout **du** chemin ».

De même qu'on peut très bien dire « au bout **du** souffle » mais pas <s>au bout de souffle</s>.

Par ailleurs, il n'y a pas de différence de genre entre les deux expressions.

Comment: Donc « au bout du souffle » est équivalent à « à bout de souffle ». De même pour «au bout du chemin» et «à bout de chemin»?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. "à bout de souffle" is a set phrase meaning "out of breath", "au bout du souffle" is unlikely to be ever used even though a contrived example might be possible.  "A bout de chemin" I can't think of ever being used at all.